# Why concurrency doesn't work when using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, pandas, concurrency, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm writing an app for inserting data from excels(with several sheets, 7-10MB, about 150 thousand rows) into databases.I parse excels with

`pandas.read_excel` and i want to reduce the time waiting for parsing big files or a list of files. The following code does the job:

```py
# coding : utf-8

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor


def meta_job(filename):

    num = int(filename[3])
    print(datetime.now().strftime("[%H:%M:%S:%f]"), end=' ')
    print('%smeta_job(%d) start' % (' ' * num, num))

    _ = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)

    print(datetime.now().strftime("[%H:%M:%S:%f]"), end=' ')
    print('%smeta_job(%d) end' % (' ' * num, num))
    return filename


def main(fileNames):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
    results = executor.map(meta_job, fileNames)
    for i, res in enumerate(results):
        print(i, res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileNames = ["d[%d]_full_10.xlsx" % i for i in range(8)]
    main(fileNames)

    # do the parse with for loop
    print("*" * 20)
    for i in fileNames:
        meta_job(i)
```

The problem is when i run the code above, the concurrency method and the for-loop use almost the same time, which the worse part is the for-loop uses less time than the concurrency.

But, when i change `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `ProcessPoolExecutor` the concurrency becomes faster(30 seconds rather than 2 mins). The following is the output.

- ProcessPoolExecutor Output

```
[16:46:38:506226] meta_job(0) start
[16:46:38:586626]   meta_job(2) start
[16:46:38:606732]    meta_job(3) start
[16:46:38:775630]        meta_job(7) start
[16:46:38:654980]     meta_job(4) start
[16:46:38:659215]      meta_job(5) start
[16:46:38:727387]       meta_job(6) start
[16:46:38:534345]  meta_job(1) start
[16:47:03:936892]      meta_job(5) end
[16:47:04:127832]  meta_job(1) end
[16:47:05:585193] meta_job(0) end
0 d[0]_full_10.xlsx
1 d[1]_full_10.xlsx
[16:47:07:104038]     meta_job(4) end
[16:47:10:099222]   meta_job(2) end
2 d[2]_full_10.xlsx
[16:47:10:867077]    meta_job(3) end
3 d[3]_full_10.xlsx
4 d[4]_full_10.xlsx
5 d[5]_full_10.xlsx
[16:47:11:305149]       meta_job(6) end
6 d[6]_full_10.xlsx
[16:47:11:392175]        meta_job(7) end
7 d[7]_full_10.xlsx
********************
[16:47:11:396162] meta_job(0) start
[16:47:25:603109] meta_job(0) end
[16:47:25:603109]  meta_job(1) start
[16:47:38:163148]  meta_job(1) end
[16:47:38:163148]   meta_job(2) start
[16:47:55:602426]   meta_job(2) end
[16:47:55:602426]    meta_job(3) start
[16:48:12:402708]    meta_job(3) end
[16:48:12:404835]     meta_job(4) start
[16:48:26:275334]     meta_job(4) end
[16:48:26:275334]      meta_job(5) start
[16:48:38:156112]      meta_job(5) end
[16:48:38:156112]       meta_job(6) start
[16:48:54:135494]       meta_job(6) end
[16:48:54:138486]        meta_job(7) start
[16:49:10:548779]        meta_job(7) end
```

- ThreadPoolExecutor Output

```
[18:26:22:154206] meta_job(0) start
[18:26:22:154206]  meta_job(1) start
[18:26:22:154206]   meta_job(2) start
[18:26:22:154206]    meta_job(3) start
[18:26:22:157393]     meta_job(4) start
[18:26:22:157393]      meta_job(5) start
[18:26:22:158388]       meta_job(6) start
[18:26:22:159391]        meta_job(7) start
[18:28:41:549298]  meta_job(1) end
[18:28:45:378990]      meta_job(5) end
[18:28:56:916256]     meta_job(4) end
[18:28:57:436046] meta_job(0) end
0 d[0]_full_10.xlsx
1 d[1]_full_10.xlsx
[18:29:13:799117]    meta_job(3) end
[18:29:17:903461]        meta_job(7) end
[18:29:19:081831]       meta_job(6) end
[18:29:19:762531]   meta_job(2) end
2 d[2]_full_10.xlsx
3 d[3]_full_10.xlsx
4 d[4]_full_10.xlsx
5 d[5]_full_10.xlsx
6 d[6]_full_10.xlsx
7 d[7]_full_10.xlsx
********************
[18:29:19:767528] meta_job(0) start
[18:29:39:749447] meta_job(0) end
[18:29:39:752440]  meta_job(1) start
[18:29:56:921441]  meta_job(1) end
[18:29:56:923431]   meta_job(2) start
[18:30:19:906304]   meta_job(2) end
[18:30:19:909290]    meta_job(3) start
[18:30:43:297230]    meta_job(3) end
[18:30:43:299242]     meta_job(4) start
[18:31:02:185841]     meta_job(4) end
[18:31:02:188833]      meta_job(5) start
[18:31:19:322984]      meta_job(5) end
[18:31:19:324980]       meta_job(6) start
[18:31:42:272996]       meta_job(6) end
[18:31:42:275983]        meta_job(7) start
[18:32:05:544849]        meta_job(7) end
```

I saw some answer in another question mentioned about `xlrd`. Is that means `xlrd` doesn't support concurrency(does not release GIL)? Thanks!

Comment: The file I/O takes advantage of python's "multithreading", however most likely the parsing of the data (once it has been read into memory) is done in python code which would mean it can not be done in parallel due to the GIL. When `ProcessPoolExector` is used each instance runs in a separate process and is not affected by the GIL.

Comment: if you mean when `read_excel` is executed, GIL will not be released, then why it takes so long to parse the excel files?(I didn't put the output of `ThreadPoolExecutor` method, while it takes almost 2 mins totally, and the end time seem quite close)

Answer (score 1):

[`Pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) uses `xlrd` to actually read the MS Excel file.  The [`xlrd` source code](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) is all Python code, so will implicitly always hold the GIL.  You'll therefore not see much speedup when using threads for concurrency.  there's also a [`openpyxl`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/) project for reading MS Excel files, but this also seems to be a pure Python project so will have similar performance characteristics

as @JimNilsson says, you might get some concurrency due GIL being released in the low-level file IO code (which is all native C code), but this isn't likely to be much